# Send the csv File fusing node

Tags: jquery, node.js

I want to upload my file on API, For that I am using multer and express. and below is my code :-

```
const app = express();
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
         res.header("Authorization: Basic X3llMVI3Mk9PdzFHOXBqcW1GaVp2NHJINjRxNDZVMlU6czIvL2JmOGM0ZDVhMjliYWUzNzgxZWQwZGY4ZDVmYmYzZjY4ZDE5OGM4YWZmY2EyZjM0YWYyNjNiNSzYgNDE1ZTE1Njc=");
        next();
    });

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
       destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '@/var/www/html/git/testplaterate/PlateRate/')
       },
       filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'achupload.csv') //Retains the original file name
       }
    })

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
    console.log("upload=====",upload);

    app.post("https://secure.usaepay.com/api/v2/bulk_transactions", upload.single('@/var/www/html/git/testplaterate/PlateRate/achupload.csv'), function(req, res) {
        console.log("files = ===");

    });
```

But When I console the "files" no console are showing. Only upload console showing.